# Android Programmatic Popup ScrollView TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Whats wrong with this code?

It only shows the grey popup window, no ScrollView or TextView appear.

However, if I add the button denoted by the false branch, the button appears.

Here I am adding more text, because SO won't let me post without more text.

Thanks!

```
static PopupWindow DebugScreen( Activity a )
{
    final PopupWindow popUp = new PopupWindow( a );

    final View cv = a.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById( android.R.id.content );

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP );
    FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout( a );
    fl.setLayoutParams(p);

    final ScrollView sv = new ScrollView( a );
    final TextView tv = new TextView( a );

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (cv.getHeight() * 0.9), Gravity.TOP);

    tv.setText("Hello World");
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setLayoutParams( lp );

    sv.addView(tv, lp);

    if ( false ) {
        final Button b;
        b = new Button(a);
        b.setText("abc123");
        b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        fl.addView(b);
    }

    popUp.setContentView(fl);

    popUp.showAtLocation(cv, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    popUp.setFocusable(false);
    popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    popUp.setTouchable(true);

    popUp.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                popUp.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popUp.update( 0, 0, (int) (cv.getWidth() * 0.9), cv.getHeight() );
    return( popUp );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed  `fl.addView(sv);` to add ScrollView to FrameLayout. Add it before  `popUp.setContentView(fl);` to see the TextView.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I added that (pretty sure it was there in a previous version), but I still get a grey box with no content.

Comment: Are you sure you add fl.addView(sv) before the popUp.setContentView(fl)? Works fine for me

Comment: I did.        tv.setText("Hello World");
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setLayoutParams( lp );

        sv.addView(tv, lp);
        fl.addView( sv );

        if ( false ) {
            final Button b;
            b = new Button(a);
            b.setText("abc123");
            b.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            fl.addView(b);
        }

        popUp.setContentView(fl);

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, this turns out to the text color was too close to the background color.  Thanks for your help!